# IBM Watson Assistant: How to make query result from Db2 downloadable as CSV file?

Tags: node.js, csv, db2, ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I am writing a chatbot program with IBM Watson Assistant in Node.js with Db2 and was wondering if there was a way to add my query results in a CSV file?

The csv file will then be downloaded by the user.

```
var data = conn.querySync('SELECT DISTINCT "Commodity" FROM TRADES WHERE "Aggregate_Level"=2');
```

I did some research and most that i found was codes for the command line interface.

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries to generate all kind of file types, including a CSV file. It is done by your app from the query result.

In Watson Assistant, you cannot upload or pass through files. But you can respond with a link to where a file is stored. The file could be in Cloud Object Storage (COS) or somewhere else.

To get your data from Db2 accessible in the chatbot,

1. generate a CSV and store it on COS (upload the file to a bucket),
2. generate a download link to the file, there are options to let the link expire within minutes, e.g., for security reasons,
3. pass that link to Watson Assistant and
4. let the chatbot return the link to the user in a response.

The user could then click the link to download the file.

The [IBM Cloud solution tutorials](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/solution-tutorials) have instructions and code for all of the above, but not within a single tutorial. Look for "secure file storage" and for "database-driven chatbot" as a starter.